# Numpy : resize array

Tags: numpy, scipy

I have two Numpy array whose size is 994 and 1000. As such I when I am doing the below operation:

```
X * Y
```

I get error that "**ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (994) (1000)**"

Hence as per fix I am trying to pad extras / trailing zeros to the array which great size by below method:

```
padzero = 0
if(bw.size > w.size):
    padzero = bw.size - w.size
    w = np.pad(w,padzero, 'constant', constant_values=0)
if(bw.size < w.size):
    padzero = w.size - bw.size
    bw = np.pad(bw,padzero, 'constant', constant_values=0)
```

But now the issue comes that if the size difference is 6 then 12 0's are getting padded in the array - which exactly should be six in my case.

I tried many ways to achieve this but its not resulting to resolve the issue. If I try he below way:

```
bw = np.pad(bw,padzero/2, 'constant', constant_values=0)

ValueError: Unable to create correctly shaped tuple from 3.0
```

How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a = np.array([1, 2, 3])`

To insert zeros front:

```
np.pad(a,(2,0),'constant', constant_values=0)
array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3])
```

To insert zeros back:

```
np.pad(a,(0,2),'constant', constant_values=0)
array([1, 2, 3, 0, 0])
```

Front and back:

```
 np.pad(a,(1,1),'constant', constant_values=0)
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 0])
```